# Passing Subroutine to Perl Subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm trying to make a subroutine that mimics Perl6/Raku's `dir`.  `dir` can search directories very easily and quickly, with file tests in a directory.

I'm trying to add a recursive option to `dir`.

I have a script that can accomplish this, but I'm trying to add a recursive option using `File::Find` script that I already know works:

```
use File::Find;
my @files;
find({ wanted => \&process_file, no_chdir => 1 }, '.');
sub process_file {
    if ((-f $_) && ($_ =~ m/\.pl$/)) {#various tests on the files
            push @files, $_;
#        print "This is a file: $_\n";
    }
}
```

However, I want to do everything in a single subroutine.

I have tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';
use Carp 'confess';
use File::Find 'find';

sub dir { # a Perl5 mimic of Perl6/Raku's "dir"
    my %args = ( # default arguments listed below
        tests => 'f', dir => '.', regex   => '.', recursive => 0,
    @_, # argument pair list goes here
    );
    if ($args{tests} =~ m/[^rwxoRWXOezfdlpSbctugkTB]/){# sMAC returns are non-boolean, and are excluded
        confess "There are some unrecognized characters in $args{tests}";
    }
    my @items = split '', $args{tests};
    my $tests = '-' . join (' -', @items);
    undef @items;
    $args{regex} = qr/$args{regex}/;
    opendir my $dh, $args{dir} or die "Can't opendir on $args{dir}: $!";
    while (my $item = readdir $dh) {
        if (($item !~ $args{regex}) or ($item =~ m/^\.{1,2}$/)) { next  }
        my $i = "$args{dir}/$item";
        if (not defined $i) {
            confess "\$i isn't defined.";
        }
        my $rv = eval "${tests} \$i" || 0;
        if ($rv == 0) { next }
        if ($args{dir} eq '.') {
            push @items, $item
        } else {
            push @items, $i
        }
    }
# this is the new part, and what doesn't work
    if ($args{recursive} == 1) {
        find({
            wanted => \sub {
                if ((eval "${tests} $_") && ($_ =~ /$args{regex}/)) {
                    push @items, $_;
                }
            },
            chdir => 1,
            '.'
        });
    }
    @items
}
foreach my $pl (dir(recursive => 1, regex => '\.pl$')) {
    say $pl
}
```

this gives an error:

```
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at clean.pl line 44
```

I think that this is because of the `find` function in the bottom, as the error indicates.

[Passing one subroutine to another subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914308/passing-one-subroutine-to-another-subroutine) is somewhat similar to my question, but I don't see how to apply there to my case.

Passing `wanted => sub` and `wanted => \sub` gives the same error.

How can I get this `wanted` subroutine to pass to `find` without errors?

Comment: `sub {...}` returns a code reference; `\sub {}` would be a reference to a code reference, not something you usually would want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl tries to use every odd argument as hash key and every even one as hash value, so with an odd number of arguments you get that "odd number of arguments" error cause you put all arguments to `find` in an anonymous hash ref. The file name / path has no hash key, so move that out of the hashref.

Then pass the `wanted` routine like this:

```
wanted => sub { ... }
```

That said, my File::Find only knows `no_chdir`, not `chdir`, so you probably want to switch the value.

This works for me:

```perl
find(
    {
        wanted => sub {
            if ((eval "${tests} $_") && ($_ =~ /$args{regex}/)) {
                push @items, $_;
            }
        },
        no_chdir => 0,
    },
    '.'    # File outside the hash ref
);
```

Comment: I might add, that for my purposes, `no_chir = 1` worked better.  Thank you for a great solution!